# Dota 2 is very slow

Tags: games, steam

Hi I just installed Ubuntu and Dota 2 lags a lot even on the main menu.  I don’t understand why because the computer has decent hardware and I am using proprietary nvidia drivers. My graphics card is a geforce 1050 and the driver is from the Ubuntu update center (nvidia-460).

Thank you for your time

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Having the same issue on Ubuntu 20